# how can I pass over a string on several txt files

Tags: text-processing, paste

I have a data like this but much bigger. So I have a df1.txt as follow

```
sp|O15304|SIVA_HUMAN    MPKRSCPFADVAPLQLKVRVSQRELSRGVCAERYSQEVFEKTKRLLFLGAQAYLDHVWDEGCAVVHLPESPKPGPTGAPRAARGQMLIGPDGRLIRSLGQASEADPSGVASIACSSCVRAVDGKAVCGQCERALCGQCVRTCWGCGSVACTLCGLVDCSDMYEKVLCTSCAMFET 
tr|A0A1B1L9R9|A0A1B1L9R9_BACTU  MNKQLFLASLKETQKSILSYACGAALYLWLLIWIFPSMVSAKGLNELIAAMPDSVKKIVGMESPIQNVMDFLAGEYYSLLFIIILTIFCVTVATHLIARHVDKGAMAYLLATPVSRVQIAITQATVLILGLLIIVSVTYVAGLVGAEWFLQDNNLNKELFLKINIVGGLIFLVVSAYSFFFSCICNDERKALSYSASLTILFFVLDMVGKLSDKLEWMKNLSLFTLFRPKEIAEGAYNIWPVSIGLIAGALCIFIVAIVVFKKRDLPL
```

and I have df2.txt as follow

```
sp|O15304|SIVA_HUMAN    IGPDGR
```

I am trying to join them both together so I do the following

```
join df1.txt df2.txt | awk '{gsub($3, tolower($3), $2) ; print $1 "\t" $2}' > out.txt
```

I expect to have this

```
sp|O15304|SIVA_HUMAN    MPKRSCPFADVAPLQLKVRVSQRELSRGVCAERYSQEVFEKTKRLLFLGAQAYLDHVWDEGCAVVHLPESPKPGPTGAPRAARGQMLigpdgrLIRSLGQASEADPSGVASIACSSCVRAVDGKAVCGQCERALCGQCVRTCWGCGSVACTLCGLVDCSDMYEKVLCTSCAMFET
tr|A0A1B1L9R9|A0A1B1L9R9_BACTU  MNKQLFLASLKETQKSILSYACGAALYLWLLIWIFPSMVSAKGLNELIAAMPDSVKKIVGMESPIQNVMDFLAGEYYSLLFIIILTIFCVTVATHLIARHVDKGAMAYLLATPVSRVQIAITQATVLILGLLIIVSVTYVAGLVGAEWFLQDNNLNKELFLKINIVGGLIFLVVSAYSFFFSCICNDERKALSYSASLTILFFVLDMVGKLSDKLEWMKNLSLFTLFRPKEIAEGAYNIWPVSIGLIAGALCIFIVAIVVFKKRDLPL
```

but instead I am having this

```
sp|O15304|SIVA_HUMAN    MPKRSCPFADVAPLQLKVRVSQRELSRGVCAERYSQEVFEKTKRLLFLGAQAYLDHVWDEGCAVVHLPESPKPGPTGAPRAARGQMLigpdgrLIRSLGQASEADPSGVASIACSSCVRAVDGKAVCGQCERALCGQCVRTCWGCGSVACTLCGLVDCSDMYEKVLCTSCAMFET
```

, how can I solve it?

Comment: Why would you expect to have the `tr` line in the output? The only way I can see of obtaining your desired output from the two example files is `cat df1.txt`, which presumably isn't what you're intending.

Comment: @roaima I want to have all the ones that are in the df1.txt, just modify by the df2.txt

Comment: And the others passed through unchanged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the join command. You need to use `-a 1`.

From `man join`

```
-a FILENUM
       also print unpairable lines from file FILENUM, where
       FILENUM is 1 or  2,  corresponding to FILE1 or FILE2
```

i.e. the final command is

```
join -a 1 df1.txt df2.txt | awk '{gsub($3, tolower($3), $2) ; print $1 "\t" $2}' > out.txt
```

#### Background

When troubleshooting, you should test each part of the pipe sequentially. `join df1.txt df2.txt` only outputs lines that are in both files. To include lines in `df1.txt` that have no match in `df2.txt`, use `-a 1` as above.

Comment: I have a MAC, should still this work? because when I run it it seems I have a syntax issue

Comment: It does give me output with I use without a but as soon as I add -a 1 or 2, it gives me like `usage: join [-a fileno | -v fileno ] [-e string] [-1 field] [-2 field]
            [-o list] [-t char] file1 file2`

Comment: @Learner I've changed the position of the option. Could you please try again? (Often OS X ships very old versions of command line tools, because Apple doesn't like the open-source GPL licence. As an aside, I'd recommend installing from an unofficial repository.)