# how can I merge two txt files by one similar string

Tags: text-processing

I have a data like this as an example

```
sp|O15304|SIVA_HUMAN    MPKRSCPFADVAPLQLKVRVSQRELSRGVCAERYSQEVFEKTKRLLFLGAQAYLDHVWDEGCAVVHLPESPKPGPTGAPRAARGQMLIGPDGRLIRSLGQASEADPSGVASIACSSCVRAVDGKAVCGQCERALCGQCVRTCWGCGSVACTLCGLVDCSDMYEKVLCTSCAMFET 
tr|A0A1B1L9R9|A0A1B1L9R9_BACTU  MNKQLFLASLKETQKSILSYACGAALYLWLLIWIFPSMVSAKGLNELIAAMPDSVKKIVGMESPIQNVMDFLAGEYYSLLFIIILTIFCVTVATHLIARHVDKGAMAYLLATPVSRVQIAITQATVLILGLLIIVSVTYVAGLVGAEWFLQDNNLNKELFLKINIVGGLIFLVVSAYSFFFSCICNDERKALSYSASLTILFFVLDMVGKLSDKLEWMKNLSLFTLFRPKEIAEGAYNIWPVSIGLIAGALCIFIVAIVVFKKRDLPL
```

and I have another data like the following which has some similar strings

```
tr|A0A1B1L9R9|A0A1B1L9R9_BACTU This is just an example 1-20-100
```

I want to be able to match the two data and anywhere that it has similar string from second txt to the first test, paste the part that is in the second text file . For example.

in the first data I have this

```
sp|O15304|SIVA_HUMAN
tr|A0A1B1L9R9|A0A1B1L9R9_BACTU
```

in the second data I have only this which matches to one of the first data

```
tr|A0A1B1L9R9|A0A1B1L9R9_BACTU
```

so the output will be like this

```
sp|O15304|SIVA_HUMAN    MPKRSCPFADVAPLQLKVRVSQRELSRGVCAERYSQEVFEKTKRLLFLGAQAYLDHVWDEGCAVVHLPESPKPGPTGAPRAARGQMLIGPDGRLIRSLGQASEADPSGVASIACSSCVRAVDGKAVCGQCERALCGQCVRTCWGCGSVACTLCGLVDCSDMYEKVLCTSCAMFET 
tr|A0A1B1L9R9|A0A1B1L9R9_BACTU This is just an example 1-20-100 MNKQLFLASLKETQKSILSYACGAALYLWLLIWIFPSMVSAKGLNELIAAMPDSVKKIVGMESPIQNVMDFLAGEYYSLLFIIILTIFCVTVATHLIARHVDKGAMAYLLATPVSRVQIAITQATVLILGLLIIVSVTYVAGLVGAEWFLQDNNLNKELFLKINIVGGLIFLVVSAYSFFFSCICNDERKALSYSASLTILFFVLDMVGKLSDKLEWMKNLSLFTLFRPKEIAEGAYNIWPVSIGLIAGALCIFIVAIVVFKKRDLPL
```

Comment: So you have strings like "A1 B1" and "A2 B2".  If "A2" = "A1", set "A1"= "A1 B1 B2"? I'm new at regexp but I think you can use (^.*)\s(.*) to capture the "part between the beginning of the line and the whitespace" and "the remainder"  So I guess you would have the comparison pull out the first part and the remainder into variables, repeat for the line it would be compared to and use logic to build the result.  Are you looking through all the lines in a file and merging the ones with similar 'first part's?

Comment: Can you explain how exactly this differs from your previous question [how can I pass over a string on several txt files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490233/how-can-i-pass-over-a-string-on-several-txt-files)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I pass over a string on several txt files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490233/how-can-i-pass-over-a-string-on-several-txt-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Bash script like this should work, altough there may be even shorter methods.

`file1.txt`:

```
sp|O15304|SIVA_HUMAN    MPKRSCPFADVAPLQLKVRVSQRELSRGVCAERYSQEVFEKTKRLLFLGAQAYLDHVWDEGCAVVHLPESPKPGPTGAPRAARGQMLIGPDGRLIRSLGQASEADPSGVASIACSSCVRAVDGKAVCGQCERALCGQCVRTCWGCGSVACTLCGLVDCSDMYEKVLCTSCAMFET 
tr|A0A1B1L9R9|A0A1B1L9R9_BACTU  MNKQLFLASLKETQKSILSYACGAALYLWLLIWIFPSMVSAKGLNELIAAMPDSVKKIVGMESPIQNVMDFLAGEYYSLLFIIILTIFCVTVATHLIARHVDKGAMAYLLATPVSRVQIAITQATVLILGLLIIVSVTYVAGLVGAEWFLQDNNLNKELFLKINIVGGLIFLVVSAYSFFFSCICNDERKALSYSASLTILFFVLDMVGKLSDKLEWMKNLSLFTLFRPKEIAEGAYNIWPVSIGLIAGALCIFIVAIVVFKKRDLPL
```

`file2.txt`:

```
tr|A0A1B1L9R9|A0A1B1L9R9_BACTU This is just an example 1-20-100
```

`merge.sh`:

```
fileone="file1.txt"
filetwo="file2.txt"
IFS=$'\n'
for line in `cat $fileone`; do
    #convert to array
    IFS=' '
    read -ra parts -d '' <<< "$line"

    other_text=$(cat $filetwo | sed -n -e "s/^${parts[0]} //p")
    echo "${parts[0]} $other_text ${parts[1]}"
done
```

This script reads `file1.txt` line per line, then checks if the prefix `${parts[0]}` is contained in the second file `file2.txt` and then merges the strings together.

How `sed -n -e "s/^${parts[0]} //p` works:

- `-n` means not to print anything by default.
- `-e` is followed by a sed command.
- `s` is the pattern replacement command.
- The regular expression `^${parts[0]` will match lines that begin with `${parts[0]`, which is our prefix (e.g.; `sp|O15304|SIVA_HUMAN`).
- The match, e.g. `sp|O15304|SIVA_HUMAN`, is replaced by the empty string.
- `p` will print the transformed line. (which will be stored in the variable `other_text`)

Also, see [this detailed explaination](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24151/112611) of this particular `sed` command.

To redirect the ouput in a file you can run `./merge.sh > output.txt`.
You can make the script more flexible by setting `fileone=$1` and `filetwo=$2` and specify the files as arguments instead, like this: `./merge.sh file1.txt file2.txt`