# how to add part of similar string from one file to another file

Tags: bash

I have a txt data like this (df1.txt)

```
>tr|A0A1B1L9R9|A0A1B1L9R9_BACTU 
MNKQLFLASLKETQKSILSYACGAALYLWLLIWIFPSMVSAKGLNELIAAMPDSVKKIVG
MESPIQNVMDFLAGEYYSLLFIIILTIFCVTVATHLIARHVDKGAMAYLLATPVSRVQIA
ITQATVLILGLLIIVSVTYVAGLVGAEWFLQDNNLNKELFLKINIVGGLIFLVVSAYSFF
FSCICNDERKALSYSASLTILFFVLDMVGKLSDKLEWMKNLSLFTLFRPKEIAEGAYNIW
PVSIGLIAGALCIFIVAIVVFKKRDLPL
>sp|O15304|SIVA_HUMAN 
MPKRSCPFADVAPLQLKVRVSQRELSRGVCAERYSQEVFEKTKRLLFLGAQAYLDHVWDE
GCAVVHLPESPKPGPTGAPRAARGQMLIGPDGRLIRSLGQASEADPSGVASIACSSCVRA
VDGKAVCGQCERALCGQCVRTCWGCGSVACTLCGLVDCSDMYEKVLCTSCAMFET
```

and I have a txt data like this (df2.txt)

```
tr|A0A1B1L9R9|A0A1B1L9R9_BACTU ABC transporter permease OS=Bacillus thuringiensis OX=1428 GN=berB PE=4 SV=1
sp|O15304|SIVA_HUMAN Apoptosis regulatory protein Siva OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=SIVA1 PE=1 SV=2
```

I want to merge them together based on the similar info 
so I want to have a output like this

```
>tr|A0A1B1L9R9|A0A1B1L9R9_BACTU ABC transporter permease OS=Bacillus thuringiensis OX=1428 GN=berB PE=4 SV=1
MNKQLFLASLKETQKSILSYACGAALYLWLLIWIFPSMVSAKGLNELIAAMPDSVKKIVG
MESPIQNVMDFLAGEYYSLLFIIILTIFCVTVATHLIARHVDKGAMAYLLATPVSRVQIA
ITQATVLILGLLIIVSVTYVAGLVGAEWFLQDNNLNKELFLKINIVGGLIFLVVSAYSFF
FSCICNDERKALSYSASLTILFFVLDMVGKLSDKLEWMKNLSLFTLFRPKEIAEGAYNIW
PVSIGLIAGALCIFIVAIVVFKKRDLPL
>sp|O15304|SIVA_HUMAN Apoptosis regulatory protein Siva OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=SIVA1 PE=1 SV=2
MPKRSCPFADVAPLQLKVRVSQRELSRGVCAERYSQEVFEKTKRLLFLGAQAYLDHVWDE
GCAVVHLPESPKPGPTGAPRAARGQMLIGPDGRLIRSLGQASEADPSGVASIACSSCVRA
VDGKAVCGQCERALCGQCVRTCWGCGSVACTLCGLVDCSDMYEKVLCTSCAMFET
```

I am trying this with no success, any thought ?

```
cat df1.txt | seqkit replace -k df2.txt -p '(.+)' -r '$1 {kv}'
```

Comment: is this part of the [previous string of questions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490367/how-can-i-merge-two-txt-files-by-one-similar-string)

Comment: @Jeff Schaller yes

Comment: Is it *different* from them? I don't think you should write the same question three times.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller this is different if it was the same I would not ask. actually if I ask they say why you ask three times, if I write everything in one question they say it is too many question and confusing . which way is best ?

Comment: well, that's two of us that you've confused with *very* similar questions, so it might help prevent accidental closure of these questions by giving an indication as to how they're different.  All 3 sound *to me* like you're trying to join text from two different files, both of which have had the same filename and very similar data.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller yes my problem is manipulating from one file to another. differences is that the two others I was mainly working to combine and lower case then this one I only work on a part of text and replace it . that is all about this question . look at the output

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in Awk:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR {a[">"$1] = ">"$0; next} $1 in a {$1 = a[$1]} 1
' df2.txt df1.txt
```

Ex.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[">"$1] = ">"$0; next} $1 in a {$1 = a[$1]} 1' df2.txt df1.txt 
>tr|A0A1B1L9R9|A0A1B1L9R9_BACTU ABC transporter permease OS=Bacillus thuringiensis OX=1428 GN=berB PE=4 SV=1
MNKQLFLASLKETQKSILSYACGAALYLWLLIWIFPSMVSAKGLNELIAAMPDSVKKIVG
MESPIQNVMDFLAGEYYSLLFIIILTIFCVTVATHLIARHVDKGAMAYLLATPVSRVQIA
ITQATVLILGLLIIVSVTYVAGLVGAEWFLQDNNLNKELFLKINIVGGLIFLVVSAYSFF
FSCICNDERKALSYSASLTILFFVLDMVGKLSDKLEWMKNLSLFTLFRPKEIAEGAYNIW
PVSIGLIAGALCIFIVAIVVFKKRDLPL
>sp|O15304|SIVA_HUMAN Apoptosis regulatory protein Siva OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=SIVA1 PE=1 SV=2
MPKRSCPFADVAPLQLKVRVSQRELSRGVCAERYSQEVFEKTKRLLFLGAQAYLDHVWDE
GCAVVHLPESPKPGPTGAPRAARGQMLIGPDGRLIRSLGQASEADPSGVASIACSSCVRA
VDGKAVCGQCERALCGQCVRTCWGCGSVACTLCGLVDCSDMYEKVLCTSCAMFET
```